# Remove an element from list of dictionaries with Pandas element

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, pandas

Considering "b" defined below as a list of dictionaries. How can I remove element 6 from the 'index' in second element of b (b[1]['index'][6]) and save the new list to b?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10))

b = [{'color':'red','index':a.index},{'color':'blue','index':a.index}]
```

output:

```
[{'color': 'red', 'index': Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype='int64')}, {'color': 'blue', 'index': Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype='int64')}]
```

I tried np.delete and .pop or .del for lists (no success), but I do not know what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work for you

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10))
print a
b = [{'color':'red','index':a.index},{'color':'blue','index':a.index}]

d = b[1]['index']
b[1]['index'] = d.delete(6)
print b[1]['index']

Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: @HamidK if this solved your problem then don't forget to mark it as your accepted answer for people in the future.

Comment: your solution is correct if you want to remove '6' as a index title. Not the 6th element of that pandas data series. The solution will fail if you have time for example as a index and you want to remove the 6th element of it. I Voted up your solution, But I might need to edit my example in the question to point out the issue. Thanks

Comment: @HamidK I updated my answer so it deletes the element at index 6 rather than the label 6. I don't think you would have to worry anyways though, I believe `a.index` converts your dataframe to `Ints` so `drop(6)` should always work. I'm not positive on that though.